# Trying to match by class and hide element

Tags: jquery

How can I hide an specific class element based on specific id?

For example, in the code here, I'd like to hid the `<div class="base">` with id `green`

```
<div id="green">
<div class="base" onclick="prirad(1, 'green')"></div>
<div class="three_s" onclick="prirad(2, 'green')"></div>
<div class="three_v" onclick="prirad(3, 'green')"></div>
<div class="two_s" onclick="prirad(4, 'green')"></div>
<div class="two_v" onclick="prirad(5, 'green')"></div>
<div class="square" onclick="prirad(6, 'green')"></div>
</div>
<div id="blue">
<div class="base" onclick="prirad(1, 'blue')"></div>
<div class="three_s" onclick="prirad(2, 'blue')"></div>
<div class="three_v" onclick="prirad(3, 'blue')"></div>
<div class="two_s" onclick="prirad(4, 'blue')"></div>
<div class="two_v" onclick="prirad(5, 'blue')"></div>
<div class="square" onclick="prirad(6, 'blue')"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using jQuery, you would use the code `$("#green").hide();` to accomplish this. To get one of the divs inside of 'green' you could use `$("#green .base").hide();` to hide it.

[Hide Method](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Get all id green element
const allHideElement = document.querySelectorAll("div #green");
// Loop all the element
allHideElement.forEach(function(element){
  // Add the class of "isHdie" of match element,but you can do anything you want :P
  element.classList.add("isHide");
});
```

```css
.isHide{
  background: skyblue;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
}
```

```html
<div id="green">
<div class="base" onclick="prirad(1, 'green')"></div>
<div class="three_s" onclick="prirad(2, 'green')"></div>
<div class="three_v" onclick="prirad(3, 'green')"></div>
<div class="two_s" onclick="prirad(4, 'green')"></div>
<div class="two_v" onclick="prirad(5, 'green')"></div>
<div class="square" onclick="prirad(6, 'green')"></div>
</div>
<div id="blue">
<div class="base" onclick="prirad(1, 'blue')"></div>
<div class="three_s" onclick="prirad(2, 'blue')"></div>
<div class="three_v" onclick="prirad(3, 'blue')"></div>
<div class="two_s" onclick="prirad(4, 'blue')"></div>
<div class="two_v" onclick="prirad(5, 'blue')"></div>
<div class="square" onclick="prirad(6, 'blue')"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
</div>
```